# Trouble using getpivotdata with different dimensions, Vertical and Horizontal

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use getpivotdata, but not sure how to get the formula working properly. I need to have the critera of business date, Name, and then base it on my headers and return the numbered area in the 2nd image. I have multiple "Values" in the pivot that need to be included.

I have also tried an index match, `=INDEX($CD:$CN, MATCH(1,INDEX(($X2=$CA:$CA ) * (Z$1 =$BZ:$BZ) * ($Y2 = $BK1:$BY1),),0))`

where I want to put the formulas,

[image]

My pivot table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hate writing GETPIVOTDATA from scratch so I cheat and normally do it by typing = and then clicking into the first cell I want from the pivot table (e.g. Stack, 12/20/17 & Sum of Up). Excel then gives me something like this:

[image]

Then where I see hardcoded values for "12/20/17" and "Up" I change them to relative references like $A2 and C$1. In this instance for the "Sum of Up" I've concatenated together "Sum of " and then used $B2.

[image]

This dynamic formula can then be dragged down and across for the remaining cells.